# Airflow ExternalTaskSensor execution timeout

Tags: airflow

I'm using `airflow.operators.sensors.ExternalTaskSensor` to make one Dag wait for another.

```py
dag = DAG(
    'dag2',
    default_args={
        'owner': 'Me',
        'depends_on_past': False,
        'start_date': start_datetime,
        'email': ['me@example.com'],
        'email_on_failure': True,
        'email_on_retry': False,
        'retries': 2,
        'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=10),
    },
    template_searchpath="%s/me/resources/" % DAGS_FOLDER,
    schedule_interval="{} {} * * *".format(minute, hour),
    max_active_runs=1
)

wait_for_dag1 = ExternalTaskSensor(
    task_id='wait_for_dag1',
    external_dag_id='dag1',
    external_task_id='dag1_task1',
    dag=dag
)
```

If something seriously wrong happens with upstream Dag and it fails to complete during the given time period, I want upstream Dag (ExternalTaskSensor operator) crash as well, instead of hanging forever.

**How can I add a timeout to ExternalTaskSensor?**

I'm looking into documentation, but it does not seem to have a `timeout` parameter or something similar. What should I do?
https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/airflow/sensors/external_task_sensor.html

Comment: If I got your question right you can always check the status of the dag from metadb and if the status is failed you can raise AirfloException

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `ExternalTaskSensor` does take a `timeout` argument in seconds. It inherits the argument from `BaseSensorOperator` (https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/sensors/base/index.html). If you pass it `timeout=60` on instantiation, it will fail after 60 seconds.

Comment: Yeah, found it already. https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/sensors/base_sensor_operator.py#L44
Thank you for response!