# Airflow: Trigger DAG to run even when cross-dependent DAG is not finished yet

Tags: airflow

I am in the process of setting up cross-dependent DAGS using the Airflow [documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/howto/operator/external.html). I have a particular use case where my DAG B requires that DAG A runs first - however, if DAG A is delayed long enough DAG B should still run. So I'm essentially looking for a way to wire an OR operation between 2 sensors.

Say DAG B needs to run daily by 5PM then this is how I would do it in code:

```
while True:
    CURRENT_TIME = getCurrentTime()

    if DAG A completed OR CURRENT_TIME > 5pm:
       run DAG B
```

This is much simpler to do in code however not seeing how this is done with Airflow.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem, here's how I think it can be accomplished

1. You need an [`ExternalTaskSensor`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/sensors/external_task_sensor/index.html) in the beginning of your DAG-B, as told in the [Cross-DAG Dependencies](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/howto/operator/external.html) guide, to hold off the execution of DAG-B until DAG-A completes.

   - Here you must also set the [`timeout` param](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55852093/3679900) so that the sensor fails after certain maximum time
2. Then in the first *actual* task of DAG-B (that comes immediately after `ExternalTaskSensor`) set [`trigge_rule=TriggerRule.ALL_DONE`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/concepts.html#trigger-rules) to ensure that the actual processing of your DAG-B starts irrespective of whether DAG-A completes within stipulated time or not; in other words

   - execution of DAG-B will be held off until DAG-A completes, but only for a maximum `delta` duration

     - If DAG-A completes within this duration, then DAG-B will begin executing immediately after that
     - but if DAG-A fails to complete within this duration, DAG-B will begin executing anyways after the passing of this duration